# default location to install ess not works with the self installed emacs

Tags: ess, install

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I don't use emacs from its repository.

I installed  my emacs by compling from source, the default location is `/usr/local`. e.g. `/usr/local/bin/emacs`and `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.4/`.

I installed [ESS from its offical site](http://ess.r-project.org/downloads/ess/ess-15.03.tgz). The default install location is `/usr` e.g. `/usr/share/emacs/`. I don't find a way to specify `--prefix` for ESS. I run `make install` directly.

So in my emacs, I can't find S mode.

What shall I do?

Shall I reinstall emacs with `./configure --prefix=/usr`? Generally speaking, should installation from source be in `/usr` or `/usr/local`?

Thanks!

Comment: Either reinstall ESS and tell it to use your preferred directory, or else add ESS's directory to your [loadpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html).

Comment: I don't find a way to specify --prefix for ESS. I run make install directly.

Comment: You can always use `(load "path/to/ess-site")` but the default location should be checked by any emacs, built from source or not. Have you done `(load "ess-site")` first? (ESS is a bit old fashioned).

Comment: Correction: Ubuntu default instal checks `/usr/local/` but the one built from source does not.

Comment: @VitoshKa: Thanks (1) What do you mean by ess-site? I have three files with that name: `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess-site.el
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess/ess-site.el
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/ess/ess-site.elc`. (2) What do you mean by "Ubuntu default instal checks /usr/local/ but the one built from source does not"? and are you talking about ESS?

Comment: Can you also add the value of `load-path` to your problem description? (This variable holds a list of directories where Emacs searches for packages to load). I also think that for a while it was `(require 'ess-site)` rather than `(load "ess-site")` (at least this is how I load it). Also, I think MELPA provides ESS, so, unless you have a good reason to use the one you compiled yourself, you could just install one from MELPA.

Comment: @Tim, I meant that if you install emacs from source it will not include `/usr/local/` into `load-path`. But the `debian/ubuntu` emacs does that.

Answer (score 2):

One easy option is to change the default `DESTDIR` directly in the [`Makeconf`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/Makeconf#L19).

Answer (score 2):

You can try downloading the ESS tgz file, unpack it in a directory of choice (for example, I put it in `.emacs.d`) and then add

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/ess-15.09-2/lisp/ess-site")
```

to your `.emacs` file. No need to recompile anything in this way.

Comment: Compiling is optional but reference documentation is not available

Comment: But where is that  `.emacs` file that you add this text to?

Comment: @ClarkHenry the `.emacs` file (also called init file) is always in your home directory